# Prevent image zoom when window is resized (Parallax Effect)

Tags: css, parallax

I have created a simple parallex effect using only CSS. My issue is that when the window is expanded the browser zooms in on the image and the bottom starts to get cut off. Is there any way to prevent this? (https://jsfiddle.net/5268agp1/2/ If you expand the result window you will see that the bottom of the laptop gets cut off). I have tried using different sizes of that image in my local project to correct the problem but that had no effect. Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="parallex">

</div>
```

css:

```
.parallex{
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/01/09/33/laptop-3190194_1280.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Well one solution is to throw aspect ratio out of the window, if you're ok with that of course, set `background-size` to `100% 100%`

Comment: You need to specify ***what*** should happen when the window aspect is different than the picture's. Considering same height, what should happen when the window is much wider than the picture and what should happen when it's much narrower? For example, in your particular case, it might be preferable to crop [from top](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ofc08rsh/) instead of from bottom.

Comment: Did not know you could do this, thanks @AndreiGheorghiu